# flag problem in network trace in arcmap

Tags: arcmap, network, geometric-network, trace, utility-network

i want to trace using a weight filter but we i have the case, that 2 edges are overlapping and they share the same 2 junctions.  Now if you want to set a flag, you won't be asked if you want to select Edge A or Edge B.

One Edge has a diameter of 5 inches and the other one has a diameter of 8.
The trace should work by setting 5 or 8 as Weight Filter.

Normally it is working, but not when lines are overlapped. What can i do?

Programmaticaly a solution perhaps or over the İnterface?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When we have situations like this we shift the lines slightly so they are never completely overlapped, by bending the ends slightly and then displaying them parallel (with a small almost negligible gap)

[image]

The top end for better detail:

[image]

This makes them a lot easier to select/edit, but also for enabling/disabling and setting trace flags.  It also makes it a lot more obvious there are multiple pipes in the one position.

We determined that the added error due to slightly longer lines and misplacement wasn't major once you consider all other network errors introduced into the network through level changes, fitting/manhole sizes, actual pipe position etc.